# Reverse Proxy IIS - SSH

Tags: iis, ssh, reverse-proxy

I am trying to configure a reverse proxy with IIS. HTTP/HTTPS connections are working. However I'm unable to set up a SSH connection. 
I've already tried a port forwarding:

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=7999 connectaddress=Server.
```

It appears that Microsoft IIS does not support any form of SSH redirection/reverse proxying. 
Do you have any idea how to establish a SSH connection with a Reverse Proxy?

Answer (score 0):

ARR only support HTTP/HTTPS protocol it does not support any other protocol like SSH.

You could check [Application Request Routing](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing) article for more detail.

Regards,

Jalpa